# Bitcoin split payment API? (Adaptive Split Payment)

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments, bitcoin

Currently our site works with "paypal adaptive payment" and we trying to also implement bitcoins.

I would like to know that Bitcoins API can give me a split payment service?

For example:
From buyer to seller, and from seller to website (3%). All instant without holding money.

I could use "stripe bitcoin support" but is not available on my country yet.. Any alternatives?

Comment: This question might do better on the dedicated Cryptocurrency site in the Stackexchange network: [Bitcoin.Stackexchange](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com). Please don't cross-post, if you create a new question there, delete this question here.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

https://bitaps.com/api/#Create_smartcontract

That interface works like a "Create payment address", but received payment will be paid to list of addresses and rules. Amount can be splitted up to 20 addresses by exact amount in Satoshi or by percent (quota). Each calculation is made of the remaining amount by cascade.
If one of the rules is needed more than the remaining amount, then this rule will be skipped and proceeds to the next on the list. For example If you want to transfer 100000000 (1 BTC) to address A and rest amount 100% to address B, but sender sent 50000000 (0.5 BTC). First rule will be skipped, because 0.5 BTC is less then 1BTC and this rule does not work. As a result - full amount will be transfered to address B.
We strongly recommend always add last rule to transfer 100%!
Be careful: In case you not specify last item in list with quota 100% rest amount will be added to transaction miner fee.
Bitaps take 0.0002 BTC processing fee one time and execute it firstly.

Examples of rules:
If you want to pay 50% to address A, 1 Bitcoin of rest amount to address B, 25% to address C and 100% of rest amount to address D, use next construction: [{"address":A,"quota":50}, {"address":B,"amount":100000000}, {"address":C,"quota":25}, {"address":D,"quota":100}].